# Calculating a Time Difference gives a wrong result

Tags: android

When I compare two dates together
Count the amount of the day incorrectly !!!

```
    final String myDate = "08/22/2018 20:56:03";
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    System.out.println("timeeeeeeeeeeeee" + "-" + simpleDateFormat);
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = simpleDateFormat.parse(myDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    long endtime = date.getTime();
    Date d = null;
    try {
        d = simpleDateFormat.parse(simpleDateFormat.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())));
    } catch (ParseException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    Long ToCount = endtime -  d.getTime();

    CountDownTimer cdt = new CountDownTimer(ToCount, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            holder.timer.setText(""+ String.format(
                    " %d : %d : %d : %d ",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(millisUntilFinished),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished) -
                            TimeUnit.DAYS.toHours(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(millisUntilFinished)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) -
                            TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) -
                            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))
            ));
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            holder.timer.setText("done");
        }
    }.start();
```

I do not know exactly what the error is
The amount of wrong day is now calculated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mm` and `MM` are different.

`MM` is for `Month`.
`mm` is for `minute`.

So, the format must be `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss`.

And I don't know how you compared two values.

You can use `equal()` method. It compares its value. `==` compares its address.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is that you are giving the wrong date format for parsing comparing to the date you are providing, to parse a date like yours `"08/22/2018 20:56:03"`, I believe the following format would be the right one:

```
public static final String STORY_DATE_FORMAT = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
```

So, the complete solution would be:

```
final String myDate = "08/22/2018 20:56:03";
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(STORY_DATE_FORMAT, Locale.ENGLISH);
Date currentDate = new Date();
Date updatedTimeParsed = simpleDateFormat.parse(myDate);
Date currentDateParsed = simpleDateFormat.parse(simpleDateFormat.format(currentDate));
// get the differences in dates
long different = currentDateParsed.getTime() - updatedTimeParsed.getTime();
```